# stuck on about_methods.rb on the EdgeCase Ruby Koans

Tags: ruby

I'm hacking my way through the EdgeCase RubyKoans (www.rubykoans.com) and am stuck on the method starting at line 35 in about_methods.rb [here](http://github.com/jbfink/koans/blob/master/about_methods.rb#L35). Running rake fails predictably and tells me to look at line 36. I'm reasonable sure I have the assert_match correct ("0 for 2") but I don't know what's failing. It's very possible that the assert_raise(___) line should have something inbetween the parentheses, but I have no idea what that should be. Any hints or nudges?  Thanks much.

edit: here's the short snippet of offending code:

```
def my_global_method(a,b)
 a + b
end
```

-snip-

```
def test_calling_global_methods_with_wrong_number_of_arguments
exception = assert_raise(___) do
  my_global_method
end
assert_match(/"0 for 2"/, exception.message)

exception = assert_raise(___) do
  my_global_method(1,2,3)
end
assert_match(/__/, exception.message)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exception = assert_raise(___) do
```

You're supposed to substitute the underscores with the error you expect to be raised. The error is an object - what kind of object?
And what zetetic said, the regex is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

Try removing the quotes from the regex:

`assert_match(/0 for 2/, exception.message)`

Comment: D'oh, yes, I actually did have the regex without quotes originally -- thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

I just did the test,

When regex with parentheses you're supposed to use  the backslash or you'd meet nil.

```
def test_calling_global_methods_with_wrong_number_of_arguments
exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
  my_global_method
end
assert_match(/wrong number of arguments \(0 for 2\)/, exception.message)

exception = assert_raise(___) do
  my_global_method(1,2,3)
end
assert_match(/__/, exception.message)
```

end

or just fill it with (o for 2)\

both words~!

Comment: Almost exactly 8 years later, I am here to say, thank you internet stranger :) Working through the koans now and this was a great help!

Answer (score 2):

After digging the error message, that is why before this exercise, RubyKoan teaches us Regex. I forgot to put `\` before `(`.

This is my answer ;

```
def test_calling_global_methods_with_wrong_number_of_arguments
    exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
      my_global_method
    end
    assert_match(/wrong number of arguments \(given 0, expected 2\)/, exception.message)

    exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
      my_global_method(1,2,3)
    end
    assert_match(/wrong number of arguments \(given 3, expected 2\)/, exception.message)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution to this. In my version Regex comes three steps after Methods (according to path_to_enlightenment.rb.

The error message was unhelpful too:
`Expected "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)" to match /"wrong 
number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)"/`

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours in this problem, I found the solution:

```
def test_calling_global_methods_with_wrong_number_of_arguments
    exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
      my_global_method
    end
    myString = "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)"  
    assert_match(/#{Regexp.quote(myString)}/ , exception.message)

    exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
      my_global_method(1,2,3)
    end
    myString = "wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)"  
    assert_match(/#{Regexp.quote(myString)}/, exception.message)
end
```